# Select all rows under a column Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select all rows that are under column when clicking the header?  say for example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Value 1
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 2
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Value 1
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 2
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Value 1
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 2
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Value 1
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 2
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    Value 1
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 2
    </td>
    <td>
    Value 3
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

What I want to achieve is that when I click `Column 1` header it should select all the rows that are under that column like below example:

[image]

I am not quite sure how to implement this one.  If someone has a good example then that would be appreciated!  Cheers!

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Also, please clarify what you mean by 'select'. I ask as if you mean select as you would with the mouse, it's not possible with a table structure as content is selected in rows.

Comment: will rework the question shortly, thanks for notifying me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select could based on header cell index `$(elem).index()`

```js
$(document).on('click', 'table thead tr th', function() {
  let ind = $(this).index();
  $('table').find('tbody').find('td').removeClass('active')
  $('table').find('tbody').find('tr').each((a,b) => {
    $(b).find('td').eq(ind).addClass('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Column 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 2
      </th>
      <th>
        Column 3
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Value 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Value 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Value 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Value 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 3
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Value 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Value 3
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```